# Why does not work whereBetween in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a model named `Student` and this model contains some field

| id | teacher_id | roll_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | 1 | 8 |
| 9 | 1 | 9 |
| 10 | 1 | 10 |
| 11 | 2 | 11 |
| 12 | 2 | 12 |
| 13 | 2 | 13 |

I have a form that passes values `teacher_id`, `start_roll` and `end_roll`

I have a query where I use `whereBetween` method to get student information

```
$studentData = Student::where('teacher_id',$request->teacher_id)->whereBetween('roll_number',[$request->start_roll,$request->end_roll])->get();
```

where `start_roll` value is `1` and `end_roll` value is `10` and `teacher_id` value is `1` but it is strange it only return two array values where id `1` and `10` only

Again if I search `start_roll` value is 5 and `end_roll` value is `10` and `teacher_id` value is `1` but it also strange it returns an empty array

If I print the above query when search it prints like below

```
Student::where('teacher_id',1)->whereBetween('roll_number',[5,10])->get();
```

If I execute the above query hardcoded(entry `roll_number` manually from 5 to 10) then it works fine for me and it returns 6 number of the array where id start 5 and end 10

I don't know why my search is not working. Any suggestion is appreciate please

Comment: are you sure $request->start_roll/end_roll returns number? Try to convert both intval($request->start_roll) ...

Comment: @AngelDeykov, It returns two numbers but are they `string` or `int` not check it. Thanks your good opinion

Comment: My bet in the comment, but I see you got what I meant. So this solved the issue, cause I don't really see anything wrong in the code ...?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in my machin

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai, I can't understand your problem

Comment: Means that everything is working expected for me

Comment: Can you take a look at the https://phpsandbox.io/n/dark-pond-ybqo-pvusa that I have created. But its working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You should add all requested values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
Like This:

```
$queryRolls = range($request->start_roll,$request->end_roll);
$studentData = Student::where('teacher_id',$request->teacher_id)->whereIn('roll_number',$queryRolls)->get();
```

Comment: It's not working. It returns as my output

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake.Use whereIn instead of whereBetween.code changed.

Comment: I already solved my problem change the table column field `varchar` to `int`. Your solution is also working.

Comment: whereIn function will be helpful for You when You want to skip some values.